# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (34:0)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is for the contact page I've been trying to create. I've been trying to compile this, but  is giving me a Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (34:0) error. I tried using <> and </> too, but that shows unexpected expression error. I know I'm missing some tag, but I'm unable to figure it out. I'm a beginner learning React. Please help.

```
return (
    
      <div className="my-5">
        <h1 className="text-center"> Contact Us </h1>
      </div>
<div className= "container contact_div">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-10 mx-auto">
            <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Full Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="fullname"
                  value={data.fullname}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name"
                />
             </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Phone</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="phone"
                  value={data.phone}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="mobile number"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="email"
                  value={data.email}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name@example.com"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                  rows="3"
                  name="msg"
                  value={data.msg}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                ></textarea>
              </div>

              <div className="col-12 mt-5">
                <button className="btn btn-outline-primary " type="submit">
                  Submit form
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
};
```

Comment: Your very first `<div>` containing your `<h1>` is adjacent to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

use [react fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```js
return (
      <>  {/*use fragments here*/}
          <div className="my-5">
             <h1 className="text-center"> Contact Us </h1>
          </div>
          <div className= "container contact_div">
          <div className="row">
             <div className="col-md-6 col-10 mx-auto">
               <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
                 <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Full Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="fullname"
                  value={data.fullname}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name"
                />
             </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Phone</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="phone"
                  value={data.phone}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="mobile number"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="email"
                  value={data.email}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name@example.com"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                  rows="3"
                  name="msg"
                  value={data.msg}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                ></textarea>
              </div>

              <div className="col-12 mt-5">
                <button className="btn btn-outline-primary " type="submit">
                  Submit form
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </>
      );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem other than you didn't put wrapping element:

Use `<></>` as you mentioned:

```js
function someComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-5">
        <h1 className="text-center"> Contact Us </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="container contact_div">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-10 mx-auto">
            <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Full Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="fullname"
                  value={data.fullname}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Phone</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="phone"
                  value={data.phone}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="mobile number"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  name="email"
                  value={data.email}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                  placeholder="name@example.com"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                  rows="3"
                  name="msg"
                  value={data.msg}
                  onChange={inputEvent}
                ></textarea>
              </div>

              <div className="col-12 mt-5">
                <button className="btn btn-outline-primary " type="submit">
                  Submit form
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I removed an additional closing div tag and added <> </>. It worked

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap everything in 1 JSX element before returning**.

You can return only 1 JSX element.
You are currently trying to return 2 elements (i.e. `<div className="my-5">...</div>` and `<div className= "container contact_div">...</div>`)

People have already given solutions to this so I'll just sum it up.
You can wrap everything inside 1 element before returning using

1. Fragment tags **`<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`** (recommended)
2. Empty tags **`<>...</>`**

Happy coding!